# PHP Error 403 con ajax al enviar html por POST

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un error 403 en PHP al enviar por Ajax/Jquery en POST un campo con contenido etc</html

Como el campo con los datos html varia cada que se envía, en algunos casos existe el error 403 y en otros funciona normal, entonces pienso que es definitivamente el código que es lo que provoca el error 403.

No es un problema de permisos, como digo en otras funciona.

En localhost funciona todo perfecto, solo en el servidor tengo ese problema.

¿alguna idea de que podrá ser?

Nota: avces es una parte del codigo en otras esa otra parte la queu generra error, pero es un simple campo de con codigo html, aveces este simple codigo html me da error 403 y en otras no:

```
<section section-block="" class="">
<h1>View our image Gallery</h1>
<article class="GallerySection" id="">
  <figure class="miniatura"><img src="img/galeria/mini-1.jpg" full-image="img/galeria/1.jpg" image-title="" image-author="©Derechos reservados" image-description=""></figure>
  <figure class="miniatura"><img src="img/galeria/mini-2.jpg" full-image="img/galeria/2.jpg" image-title="" image-author="©Derechos reservados" image-description=""></figure>
  
  <figure class"miniatura"><img src="img/galeria/mini-4.jpg" full-image="img/galeria/4.jpg" image-title="" image-author="©Derechos reservados" image-description=""></figure>
  <figure class="miniatura"><img src="img/galeria/mini-5.jpg" full-image="img/galeria/5.jpg" image-title="" image-author="©Derechos reservados" image-description=""></figure>
  <figure class="miniatura"><img src="img/galeria/mini-6.jpg" full-image="img/galeria/6.jpg" image-title="" image-author="©Derechos reservados" image-description=""></figure>
  <figure class="miniatura"><img src="img/galeria/mini-7.jpg" full-image="img/galeria/7.jpg" image-title="" image-author="©Derechos reservados" image-description=""></figure>
  <figure class="miniatura"><img src="img/galeria/mini-8.jpg" full-image="img/galeria/8.jpg" image-title="" image-author="©Derechos reservados" image-description=""></figure>
</article>
</section>
```

Comment: Tu crees que el problema está relacionado al contenido, yo diría que no necesariamente, pero que la forma de verlo está en el código+contenido (un [mcve]), porque estoy seguro que muchos aquí han enviado HTML sin ningún problema y, viendo el contenido, pues, se ve bien, no hay manera que esto genere un 403 por si solo.

Comment: Eso, suponiendo que el 403 lo genera tu código. Si lo genera el web-server, entonces, habría que ver que dicen los logs al respecto.

Comment: @jachguate pero en otras peticiones en la que envió html por ajax no me genera el error 403, eso me tiene descolocado. En en log no hay nada porque supongo que el error 403 se genera antes de que el php se ejecute siquiera, entonces en el log no hay nada.

No se si sera porque es un servidor compartido o esta saturado, pero con otro envio de codigo html funciona.

La verdad no se que hacer amigo, no se donde esta el error.

Comment: Si el servidor no respondiera, no vieras un 403, sino un timeout. Si no se ejecuta nada del PHP, el error 403 lo está generando el WebServer, en cuyo caso generalmente queda un registro en el log. Puede ser que el web-server esté mal configurado y no lo esté dejando, en cuyo caso sería que verifiques la configuración del webserver y ajustes para que quede registro de todos los errores

Comment: @jachguate mi hosting es namecheap, ¿donde puedo ver todos los registros? he accedido a las metricas donde hay errores, pero solo descarga archivos *.gz que son ilegibles en el editor.

Comment: `.gz` es un archivo comprimido por gzip, descomprimelo. La pregunta de dónde puedes ver los registros, parece adecuada para el soporte de tu proveedor de hosting.

Comment: @jachguate problema solucionado, mi hosting lo soluciono, según ellos era problema de su firewall que negaba algunas peticiones del mod_security, pusieron mi cuenta en la lista de excepciones. Nunca fue problema mio, pero si llama la atención que hace unos días no tenia este problema y recien lidiaba con este embrollo.

Gracias por tus respuestas amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado, mi hosting lo soluciono, según ellos era problema de su firewall que negaba algunas peticiones del mod_security del apache, pusieron mi cuenta en la lista de excepciones. Nunca fue problema mio, pero si llama la atención que hace unos días no tenia este problema y recien lidiaba con este embrollo.